# Mobile site only redirects to main site home page

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

I am having problems keeping the main site displayed after redirecting from a mobile site.

If a mobile device is detected it redirects to the mobile site. There is a "main site" link on the mobile site, when clicked, which will take you to the main site. For some reason it wont stay on the main site when you click a link on the main site home page, it redirects back to the Mobile site.

I assume the cookie is not storing correctly.

```
<?php
@include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
$allow_mobile = isset($_COOKIE['mobile'])? true:false;
if (isset($_GET['mobile'])) {
   if ($_GET['mobile']=='false'){
     setcookie("mobile", "");
     $allow_mobile = false;
   } else {
     setcookie("mobile", true, time() + 31536000, "/");
     $allow_mobile = true;
   }

}


if ($allow_mobile && $detect->isMobile()){
   if (!$detect->isTablet()) {
 header("Location:http://mobilesite.mobi");
   }
}

$not_mobile_cookie = isset($_COOKIE['notmobile'])? true:false;
if (isset($_GET['mobile'])) $not_mobile_cookie = $_GET['mobile'];


if ($not_mobile_cookie==false && $detect->isMobile()){
    if (!$detect->isTablet()) {
       header("Location:http://mobile.mobi");
    }
}

?>
```

It is probably something simple but I can't see to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: What variable are you appending to the main site link?

Comment: The variable is /?mobile=false

Answer (score 1):

The key to your question is that mobile devices are still redirected *when you click a link on the main site home page*.

Your code is testing for a cookie named ['notmobile'] which does not appear to be getting set anywhere. Therefore always evaluates as false, which is why mobile users are being redirected back to the mobile site.

In your code, the purpose of the `mobile` GET variable is unclear, but taking it to mean that it permits mobile devices to access the main site, I have renamed the variable below to `allowMobile`.

Assuming `Mobile_Detect` is functioning correctly, the following code will allow a mobile device to stay on the main site following a `allowMobile=true` GET request.  This can be cancelled with a with `allowMobile=false` request.

```
@include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

// Do we want to allow a mobile to view the main site content?
// If there is a cookie, yes, if not no.

$allow_mobile = (isset($_COOKIE['mobile']) && $_COOKIE['mobile']) ? true : false;

// If there is a GET allowMobile string saying 'false', delete the cookie and deny access
if (isset($_GET['allowMobile']) && $_GET['allowMobile']=='false') {
     // Delete a cookie if one exists
     setcookie("mobile", "", time()-1, "/");
     $allow_mobile = false;

} elseif (isset($_GET['allowMobile'])  {
     // if there is any other value for allowMobile, set a cookie allowing mobile access
     setcookie("mobile", true, time() + 31536000, "/");
     $allow_mobile = true;
} 

// If we DO NOT allow mobile, then redirect to the mobile site

if (!$allow_mobile && $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()){
  header("Location: http://mobilesite.mobi");
  exit();
}

// Else, display or redirect to non-mobile page here
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That does not seem to work either though. There is a missing parentheses perhaps?

EDIT: Just saw your edit, will try now

Comment: This should work `$allow_mobile = (isset($_COOKIE['mobile']) && $_COOKIE['mobile']) ? true : false;`

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but all it does now is just redirect straight back to the mobile site.
If I leave `'if ((!$not_mobile_cookie || $not_mobile_cookie=='false') && $detect->isMobile())` out it still only goes to the home page, no other pages

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for this and the trouble. For some reason it still isn't working. I have tried different methods based on your code but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page in question - we can then see what's going on with the cookies and redirection?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work if anyone else has the same problem. I am not sure if it is even the correct way of doing it but it is working properly for me.

Thank you very much for the help [PassKit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931641/passkit), much appreciated!

```
<?php
@include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

$mobile_cookie = isset($_COOKIE['mobile'])? $_COOKIE['mobile'] : "";

$force_mobile = ($mobile_cookie == "true") ? true : false;

if (isset($_GET['mobile'])) {
   if ($_GET['mobile'] == 'true') { // must we force the mobile site? if ?mobile=true then FORCE THAT MOBILE
  setcookie("mobile", "true", time() + 31536000, "/");
  $force_mobile = true;
   } else { // if ?mobile=false then remove the force
 setcookie("mobile", "false");
 $force_mobile = false;
  }
}

if ($force_mobile){

   header("Location:http://mobilesite.mobi");
} else {

   if ($detect->isMobile()){

 if ($mobile_cookie == "" && !$detect->isTablet()){

   header("Location:http://mobilesite.mobi");
 }
   }
}
?>
```